# How to draw the free body diagram of this?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

There is a smooth light peg at C. The system is in equilibrium. The ground is rough. How do I draw the free body diagram for this? Here is the system, and my attempt. [image]

[image]

Comment: Is the peg fixed? Why does it matter that it is "light"? Is there friction between peg and rod? If there is not, then force must be perpendicular to the surface of the peg.

Comment: Yes it is fixed. No there isnt, I wrote 'smooth' peg.

Comment: @user140161 are we supposed to decipher these scribblings? Why don't you insert respectable drawings? At least, out of respect for people from whom you ask help.

Comment: You're missing the force from the peg on the rod. Or, if you're including the peg in the system, the peg is missing the forces exerted on it to keep it steady by whatever it is embedded in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force at the peg is normal to the surface of the peg - and therefore normal to the rod. In equilibrium the net torque and the net force must both be zero.

You have a force (initially unknown) F at the peg - you just know the direction.

There is the force of gravity on the rod - straight down, at the location of the peg. There is the reaction force of the rod which is not normal to the rod. You need "another" force that gives you equilibrium. This force has to be supplied by the ground, and has to point straight along the rod (again, to give zero moment).

The sum of the two forces should exactly counter the force of gravity. This should be sufficient for you to draw the diagram.

[image]